# Why does .focus() not work when .css("color","red") does on the same selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(focus_On).focus();` where `focus_on = #start_Time_Mo` does not set the focus to that input field.

Where as `$(focus_On).css("color","red");` sets the text in that field to red.

Why does `.focus()` now work?

Sample code:

- `$last_Time = $(event.target);` is set on click
- `#start_Time_XX` are created dynamically hence `on`.

After checking for a valid time range if time is out of range highlight with font color red and set focus back to that input field.

```
$("#detail_Section").on("blur", "#start_Time_Mo, #start_Time_Tu, #start_Time_Wed, #start_Time_Th, #start_Time_Fr, #start_Time_Sa, #start_Time_Su", function(event) {
    earliest = (period_Definitions["morning_Start"]).split(":");
    earliest_Time = new Date(1970, 1, 1, earliest["0"], earliest["1"], 0, 0);
    latest = (period_Definitions["evening_End"]).split(":");
    latest_Time = new Date(1970, 1, 1, latest["0"], latest["1"], 0, 0);
    test_Times = ($last_Time.val()).split(":");
    test_Time = new Date(1970, 1, 1, test_Times["0"], test_Times["1"], 0, 0);

    if (test_Time >= earliest_Time && test_Time <= latest_Time) {
        console.log("time good");
    } else {
        focus_On = "#" + $last_Time.attr("id");
        $(focus_On).css("color", "red");
        $(focus_On).focus();
    }
    last_String = "";
});
```

annoyingly this works in js fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codepuppy/w2gmK/1/)

Comment: Off topic: there is a possible bug in your [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) creation. You might want to use `0` to set the month (if you need it to be January).

Comment: Why don't you just use `$last_Time.css("color", "red").focus()`?

Comment: Using `blur` and `focus` together is usually a recipe for code ending in round-abouts. I wonder if you are experiencing some sort of circluar focus/blur issue. In your code you trigger the validation on `blur`. In `blur` you are setting the focus on to a control. I would assume that setting the focus on another control may causes the `blur` event to trigger again for the previous control. If you add `console.log("Running blur")` as the first line inside the event, does it execute more than once when you leave the control? `If you could post a fiddle with your code that would be great.`

Comment: @JasperdeVries january is not significant but I see your point. swapping from php mktime to js new date I forgot to start at zero.

Comment: @Bergi sorry tried that already no dice.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl ok yes I can see the potential here but the answer is no in my work in progress version I have console.log statements tracking the start and the end the only goes into blur once and on click once. I'll try this is fiddle and see how I get on.

Comment: @codepuppy: It should work: http://jsfiddle.net/w2gmK/2/ - creating a new jQuery instance does make no difference to your issue, but this id-selector-thing is queer.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I have come to the conclusion that you were correct in the first place. In a separate script the field which I was tabbing to is also validated and also retains focus if there is an error. What I find odd about assuming that this is definitely the cause is that the order of the console output doesn't support this conclusion and if I randomly click else where to alter focus the problem persists. Nevertheless I can see no other possible cause. Although not a good solution I have decided to clear the field upon finding an invalid time thus forcing them to re-input.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$("#[id^="+ $last_Time.attr("id")+"]").focus(function()
{
   css("color","red")
});
```

Comment: if it is id of the attribute which you have to css it

Comment: This set css just like my code set the css but did not alter the focus problem.

Comment: sadly no this does not resolve the issue. See comment above - I believe it is a conflict with another script.